# Div with absolute position overflows other div

Tags: html, css, margin

On this page: https://www.bioconact.com/satisfied-customers/ I have 4 cases. When I click on one of the 3 cases on the first row, the content box that appears overflows the thumbnail of the fourth case, on the second row:

[image]

I think it has something to do with the absolute positioning of the elements, since setting a margin-bottom to the content box doesn't help. I tried all sorts of fixes, but nothing seems to work...

Any help would be greatly appreciated : )

Comment: I tried to open the page but your firewall blocked my IP

Comment: Hi there Rishabh, should be OK now! Could you look again? Thank you so much!

Comment: I have added an answer, Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen that your website is perfect.But some addition is required to avoid the overflow.Also, this issue occurs only in mobile view.

-The **top:** property has a value set in **#colio_viewport_cases** that needs to be changed in mobile view.

-Add this css to your css file:

```
@media all and (max-width:800px){
#colio_viewport_cases {
margin-right: 20px;
top: 700px!important;
}
}
```

Comment: You're Most Welcome! I'm very happy to help:)